# Android project wont pull facebook events

Tags: android, facebook, list

Hi I am trying to make a app that will pull a list the logged in users friends from facebook into my application I am using the facebook SDK the code compiles and seems to work but hangs on the spinner animation when I select the get friends option from the menu! here is the code I am using bellow

```
public static final String APP_ID = "IDHERE";

private static final String[] PERMISSIONS =
    new String[]{ "offline_access", "read_stream", 
            "publish_stream","create_event","user_events","friends_events",
            "publish_checkins", "friends_checkins" };

private TextView mText;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private ProgressDialog mSpinner;
private final ArrayList<Friend> friends = new ArrayList<Friend>();
private FriendsArrayAdapter friendsArrayAdapter;
private ListView listView;
private Facebook mFacebook;
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Make sure the app client_app has been set
    if (APP_ID == null) {
        Util.showAlert(this,
        "Warning", "Facebook Applicaton ID must be set...");
    }

    // Initialize the content view
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Get the status text line resource
    mText = (TextView) workdammit.this.findViewById(R.id.txt);

    // Setup the ListView Adapter that is loaded when selecting "get friends"
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friendsview);
    friendsArrayAdapter = new FriendsArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.rowlayout, friends);
    listView.setAdapter(friendsArrayAdapter);

    // Define a spinner used when loading the friends over the network
    mSpinner = new ProgressDialog(listView.getContext());
    mSpinner.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mSpinner.setMessage("Loading...");

    // Initialize the Facebook session
    mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Log.d("FB Sample App", "onActivityResult(): " + requestCode);
  mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Get Friends request listener
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * FriendsRequestListener implements a request lister/callback
 *  for "get friends" requests
 */
public class FriendsRequestListener implements
        com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener {

    /**
     * Called when the request to get friends has been completed.
     * Retrieve and parse and display the JSON stream.
     */
    public void onComplete(final String response) {
        mSpinner.dismiss();
        try {
            // process the response here: executed in background thread
            Log.d("Facebook-Example-Friends Request", "response.length(): " + response.length());
            Log.d("Facebook-Example-Friends Request", "Response: " + response);

            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray d = json.getJSONArray("data");
            int l = (d != null ? d.length() : 0);
            Log.d("Facebook-Example-Friends Request", "d.length(): " + l);

            for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
                JSONObject o = d.getJSONObject(i);
                String n = o.getString("name");
                String id = o.getString("id");
                Friend f = new Friend();
                f.id = id;
                f.name = n;
                friends.add(f);
            }

            // Only the original owner thread can touch its views
            workdammit.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    friendsArrayAdapter = new FriendsArrayAdapter(
                            workdammit.this, R.layout.rowlayout, friends);
                    listView.setAdapter(friendsArrayAdapter);
                    friendsArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        mSpinner.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        mSpinner.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
            Object state) {
        mSpinner.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
            Object state) {
        mSpinner.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        mSpinner.dismiss();

    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Wall Post request listener
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * WallPostRequestListener implements a request lister/callback
 *  for "wall post requests"
 */
public class WallPostRequestListener implements
        com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener {

    /**
     * Called when the wall post request has completed
     */
    public void onComplete(final String response) {
        Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Got response: " + response);
    }


    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
            Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
            Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Wall post dialog completion listener
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * WallPostDialogListener implements a dialog lister/callback
 */
public class WallPostDialogListener implements
        com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener {

    /**
     * Called when the dialog has completed successfully
     */
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
        if (postId != null) {
            Log.d("FB Sample App", "Dialog Success! post_id=" + postId);
            mAsyncRunner.request(postId, new WallPostRequestListener());
        } else {
            Log.d("FB Sample App", "No wall post made");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // No special processing if dialog has been canceled
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        // No special processing if dialog has been canceled
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        // No special processing if dialog has been canceled
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Login / Logout Listeners
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Listener for login dialog completion status
 */
private final class LoginDialogListener implements
        com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener {

    /**
     * Called when the dialog has completed successfully
     */
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        // Process onComplete
        Log.d("FB Sample App", "LoginDialogListener.onComplete()");
        // Dispatch on its own thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mText.setText("Facebook login successful. Press Menu...");
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        // Process error
        Log.d("FB Sample App", "LoginDialogListener.onFacebookError()");
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public void onError(DialogError error) {
        // Process error message
        Log.d("FB Sample App", "LoginDialogListener.onError()");
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public void onCancel() {
        // Process cancel message
        Log.d("FB Sample App", "LoginDialogListener.onCancel()");
```

}
    }

```
/**
 * Listener for logout status message
 */
private class LogoutRequestListener implements RequestListener {

    /** Called when the request completes w/o error */
    public void onComplete(String response) {

        // Only the original owner thread can touch its views
        workdammit.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mText.setText("Thanks for using FB Sample App. Bye bye...");
                friends.clear();
                friendsArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        // Dispatch on its own thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
            Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
            Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Menu handlers
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Invoked at the time to create the menu
 * @param menu is the menu to create
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Invoked when preparing to display the menu
 * @param menu is the menu to prepare
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem loginItem = menu.findItem(R.id.login);
    MenuItem postItem = menu.findItem(R.id.wallpost);
    MenuItem getfriendsItem = menu.findItem(R.id.getfriends);
    if (mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
        loginItem.setTitle("Logout");
        postItem.setEnabled(true);
        getfriendsItem.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        loginItem.setTitle("Login");
        postItem.setEnabled(false);
        getfriendsItem.setEnabled(false);
    }
    loginItem.setEnabled(true);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Invoked when a menu item has been selected
 * @param item is the selected menu items
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        // Login/logout toggle
        case R.id.login:
            // Toggle the button state.
            //  If coming from login transition to logout.
            if (mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
                AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
                asyncRunner.logout(this.getBaseContext(), new LogoutRequestListener());
            } else {
                // Toggle the button state.
                //  If coming from logout transition to login (authorize).
                mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());
            }
            break;

        // Wall Post
        case R.id.wallpost: // Wall Post
            mFacebook.dialog(workdammit.this, "stream.publish", new WallPostDialogListener());
            break;

        // Get Friend's List
        case R.id.getfriends: // Wall Post
            // Get the authenticated user's friends
            mSpinner.show();

            mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", new FriendsRequestListener());
            break;

        default:
            return false;

    }
    return true;
}
```

}

there are also two other classes that work with the application the code for these are bellow also

/**
 * ListView Friends ArrayAdapter
 */
public class FriendsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList friends;
    private int resourceId;

```
/**
 * Constructor
 * @param context the application content
 * @param resourceId the ID of the resource/view
 * @param friends the bound ArrayList
 */
public FriendsArrayAdapter(
        Activity context, 
        int resourceId, 
        ArrayList<Friend> friends) {
    super(context, resourceId, friends);
    this.context = context;
    this.friends = friends;
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
}

/**
 * Updates the view
 * @param position the ArrayList position to update
 * @param convertView the view to update/inflate if needed
 * @param parent the groups parent view
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = vi.inflate(resourceId, null);
    }
    Friend f = friends.get(position);
    TextView rowTxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowtext_top);
    rowTxt.setText(f.name);
    return rowView;
}
```

}

```
public class Friend {
public String id;
public String name;
public byte[] picture;
public Bitmap pictureBitmap;;
```

}

any help would be great  :D

Comment: Please only post the really neccessary code fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Code looks good!

Here is one thing to try... check to see if your "@Override" onComplete() method is being called and do something there.
Eg.

```
   public class FriendsRequestListener implements
        com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener {

...
...
   @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        mSpinner.dismiss();
        // Got a response... now process it
        onComplete(response);
    }
```

Comment: I am facing exactly same problem.
yes  Overridden onComplete() method is called.

Comment: My overridden methods are not called .. but the facebook login works perfectly